# Return Selected Item Value

Tags: html, razor

So I have this select block in my code:

```
<select id="mS" name="mealSelection" onselect="">
                    <optgroup label="Generell">
                        <option selected label="Alles" value="0" />
                    </optgroup>
                    @{
                        List<List<string>> kategorien = new List<List<string>>();
                        List<List<int>> catIDs = new List<List<int>>();
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            if (reader["TopKategorie"].ToString().Equals(""))
                            {
                                List<string> nextList = new List<string>();
                                nextList.Add(reader["Bezeichnung"].ToString());
                                kategorien.Add(nextList);
                                List<int> nextCatList = new List<int>();
                                nextCatList.Add(Int32.Parse(reader["ID"].ToString()));
                                catIDs.Add(nextCatList);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                int lastPos = kategorien.Count - 1;
                                kategorien[lastPos].Add(reader["Bezeichnung"].ToString());
                                catIDs[lastPos].Add(Int32.Parse(reader["ID"].ToString()));
                            }
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < kategorien.Count; i++)
                        {
                            <optgroup label=@kategorien[i][0]>
                                @for (int j = 1; j < kategorien[i].Count; j++)
                                {
                                    <option label=@kategorien[i][j] value=@catIDs[i][j] />
                                }
                            </optgroup>
                        }
                    }
                </select>
```

Short explanation: Our professor gave us the task to create a web application in which you can order food. This list is meant to filter the food by category (e.g. Asian, fast food etc.) I used a two dimensional List, because the categories are all separated in "top-categories" like snack, dessert, and so on.

I now need a button that links to a url containing the value of the selected option as parameter. However, my professor specifically demanded to use "select", "optgroup" and "option" and I haven't worked with controllers yet. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi I'm not sure where you coding knowledge is at. But i'd recommend checking javascript or Jquery. You will need to include the libraries but with Jquery you can write something like onchange get value.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange

Answer (score 0):

Just use a script to get the new value. Because you getting it on the fly it will have to be a client side language. (Like Jquery or Javascript)

```
    <select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
      <option value="Audi">Audi
      <option value="BMW">BMW
      <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
      <option value="Volvo">Volvo
    </select>

    <p>When you select a new car, a function is triggered which outputs the value of the selected car.</p>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var selected-val = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + selected-val;
    }
    </script>
```

Once you have the value you can do whatever it is you want to do with the info. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot already, I just have one remaining question: Is there any way to make "demo" invisible?

Comment: You can assign a unique ID to your paragraph and in your style sheet write display none.